# Extracting objects using JQ for a nested json file with no named attributes

Tags: json, jq

I have a generated file (from amazon CLI) and wish to pull out some of the attributes.  Normally this would be simple with JQ, however the JSON file has no named top level attributes.

```
[
    [
        {
            "State": "running", 
            "Type": "c4.xlarge", 
            "ID": "i-somehere", 
            "Env": [
                "prd"
            ], 
            "Name": [
                "some url here"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "State": "stopped", 
            "Type": "c4.xlarge", 
            "ID": "i-somehere", 
            "Env": [
                "prd"
            ], 
            "Name": [
                "some url here"
            ]
        }
    ], 
[
        {
            "State": "running", 
            "Type": "c4.2xlarge", 
            "ID": "i-somehere", 
            "Env": [
                "prd"
            ], 
            "Name": [
                "some url here"
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

..... I would like to extract the state, Env and Name .... this should be simple   jq ".[].State"   ... however the State is nested in an object which isn't named.  How can I extract with JQ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the three attributes for all objects that have any of them, no matter where the objects occur, you can use `..`.  E.g., for the given input,

```
jq '.. | objects | select(has("State") or has("Env") or has("Name")) | {State, Env, Name}'
```

produces:

```
{
  "State": "running",
  "Env": [
    "prd"
  ],
  "Name": [
    "some url here"
  ]
}
{
  "State": "stopped",
  "Env": [
    "prd"
  ],
  "Name": [
    "some url here"
  ]
}
{
  "State": "running",
  "Env": [
    "prd"
  ],
  "Name": [
    "some url here"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thankyou.  This works great no matter where the node are in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If they're simply arrays of arrays of the objects you're interested in, you can flatten it down to just the objects by traversing each of the arrays.  Then get the properties you want.

```
.[][] | { State, Env, Name }
```